# Changing code of an existing opensource application

Tags: gpl

I want to start an IDE (GPL compatible) based on QtCreator code (that is licensed under GPL and LGPL).

Do I have to change all files/classes names within QtCreator source code because of L/GPL licenses? or just modified files? or a copyright notice is enough?

**Note:** sometimes modification within a file is just changing "QtCreator" to "My App Name"

Comment: I don't get what you're asking. You want to make an IDE, I gather, but what exactly is the problem? The license itself should tell you what you do and don't need to do.

Comment: OP asks if he is required to remove references to and mentions of the original name ("QT Creator"), including file and class names, when forking it.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, QT Creator is available under free software licenses (GPL and LGPL) that allows you to creative derivative works.

Forking this project to create **My App Name** is to create a derivative work.

The license requires you to make it clear that your **My App Name** is a fork of **QT Creator** (so that nobody that uses your version will believe that they are using the original). You are also required to *preserve* the original copyright notices and authorship attribution (so that nobody that uses your version will think that you wrote it from scratch).

The reasonable way to to this is to make sure that your IDE is clearly branded as  **My App Name**, and that you put additional copyright and attribution information in comment blocks in the files that you change.

Their is *no requirement* to change file-names and class-names when you do this.  You *may* do this, but my recommendation is to change as little as possible, to make it simple (by means *diff* or similar tools) to separate your real changes and additions from the original code.